# How to prevent youtube fragment view from reloading when orientation changes

Tags: android, android-fragments, youtube-api, android-orientation

I want to prevent youtube fragment view from reloading when orientation changes in my app. I am using `YouTubeAndroidPlayerApi.jar`

I am already added **android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize"**, but it is not able to protect reload.

AndroidManifest.xml

```
<activity android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
        android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

activity_main.xml

```
<fragment
    android:id="@+id/youtube_player_fragment"
    android:name="com.google.android.youtube.player.YouTubePlayerFragment"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
```

MainActivity.java

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    String youTubeKey = getString(R.string.YouTubeKey);

        YouTubePlayerFragment youTubePlayerFragment = (YouTubePlayerFragment) getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.youtube_player_fragment);
        youTubePlayerFragment.initialize(youTubeKey, this);
}
@Override
public void onInitializationSuccess(YouTubePlayer.Provider provider, YouTubePlayer player, boolean wasRestored) {
    youTubePlayer = player;

    //Enables automatic control of orientation
    youTubePlayer.setFullscreenControlFlags(YouTubePlayer.FULLSCREEN_FLAG_CONTROL_ORIENTATION);
    //Show full screen in landscape mode always
    youTubePlayer.addFullscreenControlFlag(YouTubePlayer.FULLSCREEN_FLAG_ALWAYS_FULLSCREEN_IN_LANDSCAPE);
    //System controls will appear automatically
    youTubePlayer.addFullscreenControlFlag(YouTubePlayer.FULLSCREEN_FLAG_CONTROL_SYSTEM_UI);

    if (!wasRestored) {
        youTubePlayer.setPlayerStyle(YouTubePlayer.PlayerStyle.MINIMAL);
        youTubePlayer.loadVideo(getString(R.string.link));
    }
    else
    {
        youTubePlayer.play();
    }
}

@Override
public void onInitializationFailure(YouTubePlayer.Provider provider, YouTubeInitializationResult errorReason) {
    youTubePlayer = null;
    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Error", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}
```

Comment: I answered something similar. Could you try this ?https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56002893/how-to-handle-orientation-changes-in-android-without-restarting-activity/56003229#56003229

Comment: Please refer this documentation page : https://developers.google.com/youtube/android/player/reference/com/google/android/youtube/player/YouTubePlayer#FULLSCREEN_FLAG_CUSTOM_LAYOUT maybe it'll help.

Answer (score 4):

You should be able to use the flags like this if you need an example:

```
// YouTube player flags: use a custom full screen layout; let the YouTube player control
// the system UI (hiding navigation controls, ActionBar etc); and let the YouTube player
// handle the orientation state of the activity.
mYouTubeFullscreenFlags = YouTubePlayer.FULLSCREEN_FLAG_CUSTOM_LAYOUT |
        YouTubePlayer.FULLSCREEN_FLAG_CONTROL_SYSTEM_UI |
        YouTubePlayer.FULLSCREEN_FLAG_CONTROL_ORIENTATION;
```

[SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55973505/how-to-prevent-youtube-fragment-view-from-reloading-when-orientation-changes/56094653?noredirect=1#comment98828710_56094653)

[Another example](https://www.programcreek.com/java-api-examples/?class=com.google.android.youtube.player.YouTubePlayer&method=FULLSCREEN_FLAG_CUSTOM_LAYOUT)

Comment: can you explain how and where I can use `mYouTubeFullscreenFlags` in my code?

Comment: added example links

Answer (score 4):

```
android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenLayout|uiMode|screenSize|smallestScreenSize"
```

Try Adding This To The Activity Tag In The Android Manifest.